# problem with getting data from dataStore in roblox

Tags: lua, roblox, datastore, leaderboard

a question about Roblox studio, or rather, about dataStore. If you save the values directly in the script by the pointsStore:SetAsync ("Mars", 19) when outputting data:GetCurrentPage() - this value is output, but if you do this via a function, the value is saved, but does not appear when the data:GetCurrentPage(). How can I save user data?

save the values directly in the script:

```
PlayerPoints:SetAsync("Mars", 19)

local success, err = pcall(function()
    local Data = PlayerPoints:GetSortedAsync(false, 5)
    local WinsPage = Data:GetCurrentPage()

    print(WinsPage)
end)
```

save the values directly in the function:

```
local function givePointsPlayer(player, points)
    local pointsOld = pointsStore:GetAsync(player.Name.."&"..tostring(player.UserId).."&"..tostring(os.date("*t").month))
    if (pointsOld == nil) then
        pointsOld = 0
    end
    print(pointsOld)
    local success, err = pcall(function()
        pointsStore:SetAsync(
            player.Name.."&"..tostring(player.UserId).."&"..tostring(os.date("*t").month),
            pointsOld + points              
        )
    end)
end

EventEditPointsPlayer.OnServerEvent:Connect( function(player, points)
    givePointsPlayer(player, points)
end)
```

answer:
[answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4vHO.png)

how do I need to save user data so that it is output via :GetCurrentPage() ??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the data from the pages, you need to write some code to go through each entry and page. Here's an example from the DevHub tutorial:

```
-- Sort data into pages of three entries (descending order)
local pages = characterAgeStore:GetSortedAsync(false, 3)

while true do
    -- Get the current (first) page
    local data = pages:GetCurrentPage()
    -- Iterate through all key-value pairs on page
    for _, entry in pairs(data) do
        print(entry.key .. ":" .. tostring(entry.value))
    end
    -- Check if last page has been reached
    if pages.IsFinished then
        break
    else
        print("----------------")
        -- Advance to next page
        pages:AdvanceToNextPageAsync()
    end
end
```

For more information, see this tutorial from Roblox DevHub: https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/Data-store